# How can I decrease power losses of H-bridge with 4 N-channel MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge

This is my H-bridge circuit. I need to change the polarity and found this circuit from the site. I need 0-200 amperes for the load. I want to use the IRF1404 and parallel them, but I have two problems:

- First, there's a lot of power losses on high side (for this example: 1.55 x 5 = 7.75 V.) How can I decrease the power losses?
- Second, what diode should I use for back EMF (VCC = 12 V, I = 200 A)?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Tip: turn off the grid before taking screengrabs. This will improve legibility and reduce clutter.

Comment: *there's a lot of power losses on high side* Yes, because you're using these N-channel MOSFETs as **source followers**. To make an NMOS fully conduct in this situation you have to apply a gate voltage that is higher than the supply voltage (here 20 V). The simple solution is to use P-channel MOSFETS. This has been discussed hundreds of times on this site so start searching for similar questions. Start with the questions under "Related" on the right of this page.

Comment: You can use true gate drivers which will ensure saturation on the FETs and turn them on much faster. Something like an IR2110S (although there are definitely more modern alternatives). These are half bridge drivers, and include a charge pump for the high side FETs. You can still use the optocouplers to drive the input signals (although I don't know if they are 20V tolerant). What switching frequency are you using? This will affect your losses as well.

Comment: It's not a good circuit - please add the link to the source of the circuit.

Comment: @Stiddily Such gate drivers only work with PWM or some other switching scheme, allowing recharging of the bootstrap capacitors. OP never mentioned how this H-bridge will be used.

Comment: @Unimportant that's true, it may not have been the best choice for their application, but a gate driver in general should lower at least their switching losses. If they are only worried about conduction losses it is a different story. I hope they aren't actually using IRF540's for 200A (they are a 28A part), but getting lower conduction losses would be a function of Rdson. You can get FETs with Rdson as low as 1-2mOhm which would be ~0.2W per FET.

Comment: Is 200A the continuous current rating required? What is the load?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to get yourself in trouble - but don't let me stop you.

As has been commented on, you need what are called high side drivers. In theory, they look something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKjRrI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V2 is usually based on a charge pump, which will provide an isolated voltage with relatively low current. Of course, if you're doing high-frequency PWM, the current may not be all that low, but that's up to you. You have not passed along any actual numbers, so there is no way to advise you.

At any rate, when the MOSFET is turned on, and Rds is low, so will Vds. This means that the gate voltage will need to be about 12 volts above the drain voltage V1. (12 volts isn't a magic number, but it's a good starting point for producing a gate voltage which will drive a standard MOSFET into saturation.)

You'll need separate voltage sources for Q1 and Q3.

You've imported a circuit which works at levels more than 100x smaller than your actual requirements, so we've no reason to trust your "20V" value for V1.

You obviously have no experience dealing with switching at these currents, so let me warn you that fast turn-on and turn-off (especially turn-off) will have major effects. Whether you make a pc board or some kind of discrete breadboard, layout details will be critical, and you MUST keep leads as short as possible. And your idea of "possible" may very well be insufficient. Just a warning.

As for flyback diodes, I suggest you go to a site such as digikey.com and do some searching.

Depending on what you use as a gate driver, you may well need to pay close attention to heatsinking your MOSFETs. A classic tradeoff in this sort of circuit is switching speed (turn-on/turn-off times, *as well as* frequency) vs power dissipation. Slower gate transitions will decrease switching noise and transient levels at the expense of increased dissipation in the FETs.

I expect your experimentation phase will be painful. You will almost certainly kill a number of MOSFETs, and if you're unlucky you'll damage your power supply and maybe start a fire. 200 amps is a level where all sorts of things can go wrong. Frankly, I think you'd be better off buying a commercial unit.

But don't let be stop you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
In fact, I do not have enough experience to do this. I want to make a polarity switching circuit and just searching on google and find this circuit, Because of the high current ( 200A ) I did not find P-channel MOSFET. So I decided to use the H-bridge with full N-channel. The frequency is 50 Hz. If there is a better offer, please help me!
thank you,

Comment: @Behnamkhorasani - Sorry, but this is not a design service. Come up with a proposed design and your reasoning for your choices in a separate question, and people will help give you pointers. Include ALL of your requirements, including the power supply voltage, switching frequency and some idea of what power dissipation is acceptable.